# Variable keys in terraform maps

Tags: terraform

In Terraform, I'm trying to create a module with that includes a map with variable keys.  I'm not sure if this is possible but I've tried the following without success.

```tf
resource "aws_instance" "web" {
    ami = "${var.base_ami}"
    availability_zone = "${var.region_a}"
    instance_type = "${var.ec2_instance_size}"
    security_groups = ["sec1"]
    count = "${var.ec2_instance_count}"
    tags {
        Name = "${var.role} ${var_env}"
        role = "${var.app_role}"
        ${var.app_role} = "${var_env}"
    }
}
```

and this:

```tf
tags {
   Name = "${var.role} ${var_env}"
}
tags."${var.role}" = "${var.env}"
```

Any ideas? Is this not possible with Terraform currently?

Comment: I will be very much surprised if this feature is supported.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, I don't believe it's possible to set variables as keys.

[Mapping](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#lookup_map_key_) with variables is possible, though. Another example is [here](https://www.terraform.io/intro/getting-started/variables.html).

Comment: @JoeyP this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57401750/2852528 should be accepted instead

Answer (score 49, accepted):

There's (now) a [`lookup` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#lookup_map_key_default_) supported in the terraform interpolation syntax, that allows you to lookup dynamic keys in a map.

Using this, I can now do stuff like:

```tf
output "image_bucket_name" {
  value = "${lookup(var.image_bucket_names, var.environment, "No way this should happen")}"
}
```

where:

```tf
variable "image_bucket_names" {
  type = "map"

  default = {
    development = "bucket-dev"
    staging = "bucket-for-staging"
    preprod = "bucket-name-for-preprod"
    production = "bucket-for-production"
  }

}
```

and `environment` is a simple string variable.

Answer (score 33):

## Update

The accepted answer describes how to do dynamic lookups in an existing map. For constructing maps with dynamic keys, in HCL2 (0.12), you can use a quoted interpolation expression in the key:

```tf
resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  count = "${var.ec2_instance_count}"
  
  ami = "${var.base_ami}"
  availability_zone = "${var.region_a}"
  instance_type = "${var.ec2_instance_size}"
  security_groups = ["sec1"]

  tags = {
    Name              = "${var.role} ${var.env}"
    role              = "${var.app_role}"
    "${var.app_role}" = "${var.env}"               # <------ like this
  }
}
```

And once [issue #21566](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/21566) is fixed, you can replace `"${var.app_role}"` with `(var.app_role)`, which is the method described in the [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#literal-expressions).

(The same caveat as below applies here as well: if `var.app_role` contains one of those literal keys as its value, then it will replace it.)

## Old answer

The accepted answer describes how to do dynamic lookups in an existing map. For constructing maps with dynamic keys, in HCL2 (0.12), you have two ways:

### [For expressions](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#for-expressions) + [`merge`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/merge.html)

You can use [for expressions](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#for-expressions) to dynamically build a map from one or more variables for your keys, and then use that in combination with the [`merge` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/merge.html) to build a new map with a mix of static and dynamic keys:

```tf
variable "app_role" {
  type = string
}

locals {
  tags = merge(
    {
      Name = "${var.role} ${var.env}"
      role = "${var.app_role}"
    },
    {
      for k in [var.app_role]: k => "${var.env}"
    }
  )
}
```

### [`zipmap`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/zipmap.html)

Alternatively, you can use [`zipmap`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/zipmap.html) to construct it in one shot:

```tf
locals {
  tags = zipmap(
    [
       "Name",
       "role",
       var.app_role
    ],
    [
       "${var.role} ${var.env}",
       var.app_role,
       var.env
    ]
  )
}
```

You can then use this map in a resource:

```tf
resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  count = "${var.ec2_instance_count}"
  
  ami = "${var.base_ami}"
  availability_zone = "${var.region_a}"
  instance_type = "${var.ec2_instance_size}"
  security_groups = ["sec1"]

  tags = local.tags // or inline the above here
}
```

One caveat is that if `var.app_role` is equal to either `"Name"` or `"role"`, then it'll overwrite your static value. You can avoid this by swapping the arguments in `merge` or reordering the lists in `zipmap`, though such a collision would more likely be a configuration error that should be caught & fixed before applying.

Comment: i think this should be the correct answer. this works fine: `"${var.some_variable}" = "value",`

Answer (score 7):

The following works with terraform version 0.11.7.  This solution uses the [map function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#map-key-value-).

```
resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  ...
  tags = "${map(
    "Name", "${var.role} ${var_env}",
    "role", "${var.app_role}",
    "${var.app_role}", "${var_env}"
  )}"
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I recently needed to set a tag key dynamically too, and managed to do it using `zipmap`:

```
locals {
  ec2_tag_keys = ["some/prefix/${var.some_var}", "another_tag"]
  ec2_tag_vals = ["some value", "another value"]
}

resource "aws_instance", "foo" {
  ...
  tags = "${zipmap(local.ec2_tag_keys, local.ec2_tag_vals)}"
}
```

It's a little clunky, but it works.

Comment: this helped with dynamically setting a map key in a data block. Many thanks.

Comment: upvoting this as terraform 12 deprecated map()

Answer (score 2):

I'm uncertain when it was added, but at least as of version 0.11.7, Terraform supports the use of variables as map keys. Here's an example of how I'm currently using it to select the AWS instance type:

In the `.tf` file:

```hcl
variable "environment" {}

...

variable "instance_types_webserver" {
  type = "map"

  default = {
    testing    = "t2.small"
    qa         = "t2.medium"
    staging    = "t2.xlarge"
    production = "t2.xlarge"
  }
}

...

resource "aws_opsworks_instance" "verification" {
  stack_id      = "${aws_opsworks_stack.verification.id}"
  layer_ids     = ["${aws_opsworks_custom_layer.verification.id}"]
  instance_type = "${var.instance_types_webserver["${var.environment}"]}"
  state         = "running"
  count         = 1
}
```

In the `.tfvars` file:

```hcl
...
environment = "testing"
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another (new) way of achieving this is via `(var.myvar): "somevalue"`:

```
resource "kubernetes_secret" "redis" {
  metadata {
    name = local.redis_secret_name
    namespace = var.namespace
  }
  data = {
    (local.redis_secret_password_key): base64encode(random_password.redis.result)
  }
}
```