# terraform map adding the "key" key instead of the actual key

Tags: terraform, yaml

This isn't a duplicate, my problem is that I'm unable to iterate through the map via the for-in structure. The keys aren't being taken from the map, they are being replaced by the word key. My intention is to yamlencode the map and send to helm, the below is similar to my actual code:

```
join("\n", [for key, value in {"a":"b","c":"d"} : "  ${yamlencode({ key = value })}"])
```

the above piece of code returns

```
  "key": "b"

  "key": "d"
```

instead of the actual keys. How do I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variable keys in terraform maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491987/variable-keys-in-terraform-maps)

Comment: No, my problem is that I'm unable to iterate through the map via the for-in structure. The keys aren't being taken from the map, they are being replaced by the word key.

Comment: Tried on https://terraform-online-console.com/ the following code:
join("\n", [for k, v in {"a":"b","c":"d"} : "  ${yamlencode({ k = v })}"])

The result is 
"k": "b"

"k": "d"

instead of 

"a": "b"

"c": "d"

Comment: This is probably a bug in the `yamlencode` function. Note that 1. if this is a representative example then you could `yamlencode({"a":"b","c":"d"})` and bypass this entirely 2. the return part of the `for` expression could be simplified to `yamlencode({ key = value })`.

Comment: @MatthewSchuchard i actually wanted to add 2 spaces infront of each entry (number of entries may not be fixed since map is dynamically obtained) hence parsing them individually . and "indent" function doesnt do that for the first entry otherwise would have used that. any ideas on how i can overcome this?

Comment: @ShaguftaOliveyuMethwani have you tried reading answers to the question I linked? This is not a bug in `yamlencode`, of course, it's only RTFM issue. `join("\n", [for key, value in {"a":"b","c":"d"} : "  ${yamlencode({ "${key}" = value })}"])`

Answer (score 0):

The argument you've passed to `yamlencode` is an [object literal expression](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/types#maps-objects). The documentation about those says:

> The keys in a map must be strings; they can be left unquoted if they are a valid identifier, but must be quoted otherwise. You can use a non-literal string expression as a key by wrapping it in parentheses, like `(var.business_unit_tag_name) = "SRE"`.

You are trying to use a *non-literal string expression* -- a reference to the `key` variable -- as the key, so you must wrap it in parentheses, like this:

```
join("\n", [for key, value in {"a":"b","c":"d"} : "${yamlencode({ (key) = value })}"])
```

Extracting that object constructor from the expression just to focus on the part relevant to the question:

```
{
  (key) = value
}
```

The parentheses around `key` tell Terraform that you want to use the identifier inside as a normal expression, referring to the local symbol `key`. By default, Terraform uses a naked identifier as a literal name because literal keys are more commonly-used than dynamic keys, and so the Terraform language optimizes for readability in that common situation.